# Пересечение и разность массивов

Tags: php

Есть два массива:

```
###<pre>array(1) {
  [60]=>
  int(0)
}
###array(4) {
  [19]=>
  string(31) "Акушер-гинеколог"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "Андролог "
  [4]=>
  string(24) "Анестезиолог"
  [60]=>
  string(22) "Бактериолог"
}
```

На выходе нужно получить массив:

```
 ###array(4) {
      [19]=>
      string(31) "Акушер-гинеколог"
      [3]=>
      string(17) "Андролог "
      [4]=>
      string(24) "Анестезиолог"
}
```

Нужно получить все элементы из массива `$arr`, которых нет в массиве `$arr2`

Comment: кажется, подходит array_diff_assoc()

Comment: Не подходит - мне нужно по ключам расхождение искать.

Comment: Тогда еще раз напиши в вопросе, что бы ты хотел в итоге получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_diff_key($array1, $array2)
```

Comment: Пробовал - не сработало.

Comment: Массивы местами поменяй - сначала большой, потом маленький в функцию передай.